# How to nest these quotes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the following code to work using nested quotes but I don't know how to triple nest them.  Here's the code I have so far but it isn't working, I get `Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token &` when I run it.

```
driver.executeScript("$(&quot;li[data-drilldown='interests']&quot;).click()")
```

It seems like there should be a better way to do this but I'm not familiar enough with Javascript

Comment: Is there some reason you have to use JSE? Why not just use the CSS selector, `"li[data-drilldown='interests']"` and click it?

Comment: For some reason webdriver errors if I do it that way unless I use a sleep statement which I didn't want to deal with.  The error is probably a separate issue.

Comment: Just FYI... using JSE is not a user scenario. It allows you to do things that a user can't do. If you don't care about user scenarios, then that's fine. It sounds like you need to investigate and try some `WebDriverWait`s to get around the wait issue.

Comment: I tried using waits but no luck, I still had timing issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just escape them:

```
driver.executeScript("$(\"li[data-drilldown='interests']\").click()");
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes in the selector as they aren't necessary when the value you are looking for doesn't contain spaces:

`driver.executeScript('$("li[data-drilldown=interests]").click()')`

or

`driver.executeScript("$('li[data-drilldown=interests]').click()")`

Because JavaScript allows the single (') or double (") quote as a string delimiter. As long as you have them in pairs that match, either can be nested inside the other. The only exception to this rule is with JSON. There, you must use double quotes to delimit your property names and your string literals.